# jacoco+gradle taskdef A class needed by class org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask canno t be found

Tags: gradle, jacoco

I'm trying to get jacoco+gradle work together. Looking at this forum it seems some people have successfully done that. But when I tried I got a strange exception.

What I did:

1.Downloaded gradle 2.2.1 and configured env variables, etc.

2.Downloaded jacoco 0.7.1 from   http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/

3.added:

```
 apply plugin: 'jacoco'
```

and

```
 buildTypes {
         debug
{
         testCoverageEnabled true
...
```

in the build.gradle

4.run gradle build

5.I got an error saying the jacoco agent jar cannot be found, etc. Error message showed it tried to search files under C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository... etc.

6.I manually unzipped the jacoco jar files and put them in the place where the error message mentioned and the error message disappeared.

7.Then I ran gradle build. I got the following new error when running the built-in instrumentDebug task:

```
Caused by: : taskdef A class needed by class org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask cannot be found: org/jacoco/core/runtime/IExecutionDataAccessorGenerator using the classloader AntClassLoader[C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\org\jacoco\org.jacoco.ant\0.7.1.201405082137\org.jacoco.ant-0.7.1.201405082137.jar]
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:612)

    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:237)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:92)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.coverage.JacocoInstrumentTask.instrument(JacocoInstrumentask.groovy:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

    at org.jacoco.core.runtime.IExecutionDataAccessorGenerator
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1315)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1068)...
```

When I used process monitor (My dev machine is Win 7), I saw there was no access to org.jacoco.core-0.7.1.201405082137.jar,which the org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask class resides in. So I think the gradle did not pass the file path to org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader correctly.

I have tried below ways but none of them worked:

1. Add all jacoco jar files to CLASSPATH environment variable.
2. Add the jacoco jar files to ant libs, gradle libs,gradle libs/plugins, folder.
3. Look at source code of gradle 2.2.1. Clueless at this moment...

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

**The main purpose is to:**

**1. Let jacoco build an instrumented apk file**

**2. Manually test the apk file (Not auto test)**

**3. Let jacoco generate coverage report**

**Update:**
I just found when executing InstrumentDebug task, the gradle starts a new process with below command:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe" -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=CN -Duser.language=zh -Duser.variant -cp D:\gradle-2.2.1\gradle-2.2.1\lib\gradle-launcher-2.2.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 2.2.1 D:\gradle-2.2.1\gradle-2.2.1\daemon 120000 744501ac-32c1-4930-82bd-59e0a9e2b92d -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=CN -Duser.language=zh -Duser.variant

As you can see the class path is hard coded, which overwrites what defined in environment variable. So the required core lib of jacoco could not be found and thus caused this problem. I'm now trying to see where this process is started and whether there is a way to change the -cp option.

**Update2:**
I finally found this process is started by gradle-launcher-2.2.1.jar. See below code. I'm now trying to see whether it's possible to change DefaultModuleRegistry and make registry.getGradleHome() == null. **In the meantime could anyone who has successfully used jacoco+gradle tell me which version of gradle are you using?**

```
public DaemonStartupInfo startDaemon()
{
DefaultModuleRegistry registry = new DefaultModuleRegistry();
Set<File> bootstrapClasspath = new LinkedHashSet();
bootstrapClasspath.addAll(registry.getModule("gradle-launcher").getImplementationClasspath().getAsFiles());
if (registry.getGradleHome() == null) 
{
  bootstrapClasspath.addAll(registry.getFullClasspath());
}
if (bootstrapClasspath.isEmpty()) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to construct a bootstrap classpath when starting the daemon");
}    
new JvmVersionValidator().validate(this.daemonParameters);
List<String> daemonArgs = new ArrayList();
daemonArgs.add(this.daemonParameters.getEffectiveJavaExecutable());
List<String> daemonOpts = this.daemonParameters.getEffectiveJvmArgs();
LOGGER.debug("Using daemon opts: {}", daemonOpts);
daemonArgs.addAll(daemonOpts);
daemonArgs.add("-cp");
daemonArgs.add(CollectionUtils.join(File.pathSeparator, bootstrapClasspath));
daemonArgs.add(GradleDaemon.class.getName());
daemonArgs.add(GradleVersion.current().getVersion());
daemonArgs.add(this.daemonDir.getBaseDir().getAbsolutePath());
daemonArgs.add(String.valueOf(this.daemonParameters.getIdleTimeout()));
daemonArgs.add(this.daemonParameters.getUid());

...
}
```

Comment: Have you followed Gradle guide (chapter 34): http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html . I haven't tried Gradle 2.2.1 but, my question to you would be, are you trying to get code coverage of your main source code using "unit tests" or using "integration/acceptance/Selenium/etc GUI tests"? If it's using your UNIT tests, then Gradle will do that for free when you'll run "gradle clean build". If you want code coverage of main source code using non-unit tests, then you have to attach jacocoagent to target JVM (for ex: in target server's Tomcat JVM where .war of an app runs).

Comment: Also, paste your build.gradle.

Comment: @ArunSangal,Thanks for reply. I've updated my purpose. I'm now stucked at #1. There is nothing special in my build.gradle. I just added what the step 3 mentions.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps.
I'm not using Gradle 2.2.1 but this is what I have in my Global Gradle file (i.e. a file in $GRADLE_HOME/init.d level file). File name can be anything with .gradle extension.

```
allprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'pmd'
   apply plugin: 'findbugs'
   apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
   apply plugin: 'jacoco'

   //NOTE1: The following soureSet section is NOT required, if your folder structure follows what Gradle says where your main source should reside, where test (Unit tests) should reside, and where other like integrationTest (integration tests code reside). If your project structure doesn't follow the Gradle defined structure, then you can define that as my source code is not under src/main/java but is under src/java. The use of "sourceSet" section in this global file is only helping to use some conventional values in this global level file for ex: see integrationTest task and jacocoTestReport task below (you can't use those values if sourceSet is NOT defined in this file and if your project doesn't following the Gradle defined structure).

  //NOTE2: Here in the global level Gradle file, I'm using values for sources for main, test, integrationTest etc as "dont_change_me" as I don't know what all projects (which will use this Gradle's global level file), will have what source code structure. The main / actual values of the sources for main, test and integrationTest task MUST be defined in the PROJECT's build.gradle file in sourceSets { main { java { srcDir 'src/java' } } } way.


   sourceSets {
      main {
         java {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
         resources {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
      }
      test {
         java {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
         resources {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
      }
      integrationTest {
         java {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
         resources {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
      }
      acceptanceTest {
         java {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
         resources {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
      }

   }

   //...more code here
   //...more code here

   // The following is necessary to get code coverage info out. Compile with debug mode.
   tasks.withType(Compile) {
     options.debug = true
     options.compilerArgs = ["-g"]
   }

   jacoco {
        //toolVersion = "0.6.2.201302030002"
        //toolVersion = "0.7.0.201403182114"
        //toolVersion = "0.7.1.201404171759"

        //This is latest than above, you may find later versions in online Maven repository.
        toolVersion = "0.7.2.201409121644"

        //OK I don't need the following folder to be created as I'll define my own.
        // reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")

   }

   //The following section is for UNIT tests (as build task in Gradle calls test task for free)
   test {
     maxParallelForks = 5
     forkEvery = 50
     ignoreFailures = true

     // I want my reports (html) files to be created in a user defined folder UT(Unit test in build/reports/UT folder) and xml files (in user defined folder UT folder) under build/test-results/UT folder.
     testReportDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/UT")
     testResultsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results/UT")

     //Following jacoco session will RUN in GRADLE's JVM session (during build / test time). This is different JVM than what many think of a runtime/Tomcat JVM session where we run a .war/.ear/etc file of an app to run that app and if you want to get code coverage of your main source code using non-unit tests from a Tomcat JVM, then see next task (integrationTest) as the following jacoco section in this "test" task is just for UNIT tests running in Gradle JVM session on a machine.
     jacoco {
        //NOTE: The following vars works ONLY with Gradle <= 1.6 version

        // Create jacoco .exec file for Unit test in a user defined location
        destPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec")
        //The following line is not that usesful acc. to my experience so commented it.
        //classDumpPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps")



        //NOTE: Following vars works only with versions >= 1.7 version of Gradle
        //destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec")
        //  classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps")
     }
   }


   task integrationTest( type: Test) {

     //Always run tests
     outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

     //Ignore the failures if any during tests and don't mark the Gradle task as failed.
     //You can comment this line if you want your gradle task to fail as soon as it finds any failing tests.
     ignoreFailures = true

     //This is telling Gradle that where it'll find class files from integration tests source code
     testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
     //What path to use in classpath for integration tests
     classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

     //My custom location where I want my html reports files and xml result times of integration tests
     testReportDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/IT")
     testResultsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results/IT")

     //Jacoco section in IT tests is NOT required here. Why as it'll never generage a coverage report this way as this way of using jacoco section in integrationTest task is telling Gradle to use jacoco in Gradle JVM and for getting code coverage you have to run jacoco/jacocoagent.jar in Target JVM (which is Tomcat or similar) by introducing jacocoagent.jar and other parameters for jacoco to Tomcat using one of Tomcat's -Dxxx option (see Jacoco help on how to do this). As the following is not required, I'm commenting the following jacoco code(otherwise if used, it'll always give you 0% coverage).
        //jacoco {
           //This works with 1.6
           //  destPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec")
           //  classDumpPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/IT/classpathdumps")

           //Following works only with versions >= 1.7 version of Gradle
           //destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec")
           //  classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/IT/classpathdumps")
        //}
  }


  jacocoTestReport {
      group = "Reporting"
      description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
      ignoreFailures = true

      //Use any .exec file found before generating coverage report i.e. it'll give you combined coverage report if you have both jacocoUT.exec and jacocoIT.exec or other .exec files in build/jacoco/xx folders.
      executionData = fileTree(dir: 'build/jacoco', include: '**/*.exec')

      //executionData = files('build/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec', 'build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec')
      //executionData = files(['build/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec', 'build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec'])

      reports {
             xml{
                 enabled true
                 //Following value is a file
                 destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/xml/jacoco.xml"
             }
             csv.enabled false
             html{
                 enabled true
                 //Following value is a folder
                 destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/html"
             }
      }

      //The following is an example of using Gradle conventional way of saying where is my main source code directory
      //sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)

      sourceDirectories = files(['src/java', 'src/groovy'])
      classDirectories =  files('build/classes/main')
  }

}
```

In Project's build.gradle, you define sourceSets section (with actual values) if your project structure if different than what Gradle says it should be. You define dependencies (i.e. for compile you need this .jar, for test or integrationTest, you need this .jar or .class from main/test etc).

Then, if you run gradle clean build, you'll get jacoco code coverage data for UT(Unit tests) under build/jacoco/UT folder in the form of an .exec file. Under build/reports/... html folder, you'll find jacoco main index.html which will show you the code coverage report.

If you want code coverage report from non-Unit tests (i.e. Integration tests etc), then attach the following parameter to the target JVM. I use Tomcat, so I'm attaching this, where testType is a variable which I use to find/tell whether I'm running IT(Integration Tests), AT (Acceptance Tests) or ST (Selenium GUI tests).

```
export PROJ_EXTRA_JVM_OPTS="-javaagent:tomcat/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=build/jacoco/${testType}/jacoco${testType}.exec,append=false"
```

and in startTomcat.sh script which I use, you'll notice I'm using the above variable and passing it to Tomcat's JVM as that's the JVM which is running my project's main .war/.ear file which has the main source code class files against which I want my code covreage data using Integration/Acceptance/other non-UNIT type tests:

```
## Tomcat command - JDK 1.6/Tomcat 6.0
TOMCAT_CMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java $TOMCAT_JVM_ARGS \
$OPTIT_JVM_ARGS \

$JPROF_JVM_ARGS \
$PROJ_EXTRA_JVM_OPTS \
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap $TOMCAT_CFG_FILE_ARGS start"
```

The above variable needs to be there in the Tomcat start script i.e. when Tomcat starts, it should get the above variable in its JVM session. Once this is done, you have to run "gradle integrationTest" then stop your Tomcat session(only then it'll flush the code coverage data to jacocoIT.exec file) and then if you run "gradle jacocoTestReport", it'll read the jacocoIT.exec file and genreate jacoco code coverage report for your main source code which your Integration/Acceptance/Selenium Tests tried to cover.